# call a method to read in the data from a file

Tags: java

The question is

The main program calls a method to read in the data from a file.he data consists of sets of lines of data, each of which contains a person's three-digit integer ID number and a donation in dollars and cents. (e.g., 456 250.00 or 123 175.34).

i have a file which contain:

456, 250.00

123, 175.34

345, 123.06

and i have this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class assignment6{

public static void readdata(int[]data,double[]donation)throws 
FileNotFoundException{
Scanner input=new Scanner(new File("setsofdata.txt"));
PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter ("setsofarray.txt");
int i=0;
while(input.hasNext()){
  data[i]=input.nextInt();
  donation[i]=input.nextDouble();
  i++;
}input.close();
output.println(data[i]+"      "+donation[i]);
output.close();
}

public static void main(String[]args)throws FileNotFoundException{
readdata(new int[17],new double[17]);
}
}
```

why it is inputmismatch when i complie it?

---

The main program calls a method to read in the data from a file. (This file will declare and create the input file variable. Don’t forget to throw exceptions.) The data consists of sets of lines of data, each of which contains a person's three-digit integer ID number and a donation in dollars and cents. (e.g., 456 250.00 or 123 175.34). The file is read until end-of-file is reached. The method returns how many sets of data were read in.

Comment: You'll be printing the same line (`output.println(data[i]+"      "+donation[i]);`) repeatedly.

Comment: Here's your actual error. `Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: setsofdata.txt` **`>>>>>(The system cannot find the file specified)<<<<<`**
 `at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at assignment6.readdata(assignment6.java:7)
 at assignment6.main(assignment6.java:21)`

Comment: @FailingCoder it couldn't even print,it gives an error.

Comment: The system cannot find the file specified, you have to make it first. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/file_createnewfile.htm

Comment: i did, if i only read in one data, it worked but i need read two.

Comment: What is in this said file? What are you expecting from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counting 1 line as 1 set would be:

```
 private static int readdata()throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner input=new Scanner(new File("setsofdata.txt"));
        int countSets=0;
        String line="";
        while(input.hasNextLine()){
             line=input.nextLine();
            countSets++;
        }
        System.out.println("Sets of data read are "+countSets);
        return countSets;

    }
    public static void main(String[]args)throws FileNotFoundException{
        readdata();
    }
```

and if you want to count ID and donation as separate set, it would be:

```
 while(input.hasNextLine()){
             line=input.next();
            countSets++;
 }
```

Comment: im sorry if i confused you. I want my program to read in these data and print them out in output screen

Comment: so why are using PrintWriter? PrintWriter is for writing data to a file

Comment: so how should i fix it, im very new to java

Comment: can you post the actual question?

Comment: `System.out.println();`

Comment: This is how you read a data from  a file and print the output while(input.hasNextLine()){
                String line=input.nextLine();
                System.out.println(line);
            }

Comment: apologies to confusion, the actual question is up there.

Comment: thank you for both of your help@FailingCoder and @Liam Wilson